# Compute XY coordinate given a directed vector

Tags: r, vector, coordinates, scatter-plot

I have these data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(xstart=rnorm(5),ystart=rnorm(5),
                 xmax=rnorm(5),ymax=rnorm(5),
                 length=runif(5,0,1))
```

Where `xstart` and `ystart` define the start coordinate of a vector (i.e., a line in this 2D space with a direction), and `length` defines its length. `xmax` and `ymax` define the direction of the vector (i.e, `(ymax - ystart)/(xmax - xstart)` is the slope).

I'm looking for a function that will compute the xend and yend coordinates of each vector. Essentially this can be solved using the equations:

```
length^2 = (xend - xstart)^2 + (yend - ystart)^2
yend = beta*(xend - xstart)
```

where:

```
beta = (ymax - ystart)/(xmax - xstart)
```

Comment: This sounds like it needs to use `atan2(ymax-ystart, xmax-xstart)` and then `sin` and `cos`, where the geometry is from there self-explanatory. Have you tried that route? (The advantage of using `atan2` over just slope is that there are places where slope is `Inf` where `atan2` is still defined within the finite realm.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pure geometry. I suggest using `atan2` in place of slope, since it is finitely-defined (vice a slope of `Inf` or `-Inf` with vertical lines).

```
angles <- atan2(df$ymax - df$ystart, df$xmax - df$xstart)
df$xend <- df$xstart + df$length * cos(angles)
df$yend <- df$ystart + df$length * sin(angles)
# and to verify the resulting lengths are as-desired
df$len2 <- sqrt( (df$xend - df$xstart)^2 + (df$yend - df$ystart)^2 )
df
#       xstart     ystart       xmax        ymax    length       xend        yend      len2
# 1 -0.6264538 -0.8204684  1.5117812 -0.04493361 0.8209463  0.1452983 -0.54055500 0.8209463
# 2  0.1836433  0.4874291  0.3898432 -0.01619026 0.6470602  0.4288186 -0.11138308 0.6470602
# 3 -0.8356286  0.7383247 -0.6212406  0.94383621 0.7829328 -0.2704346  1.28011746 0.7829328
# 4  1.5952808  0.5757814 -2.2146999  0.82122120 0.5530363  1.0433885  0.61133438 0.5530363
# 5  0.3295078 -0.3053884  1.1249309  0.59390132 0.5297196  0.6804608  0.09139217 0.5297196
```

So, as a function, something like:

```
somefunc <- function(xstart, ystart, xmax, ymax, len) {
  angles <- atan2(ymax - ystart, xmax - xstart)
  xend <- xstart + len * cos(angles)
  yend <- ystart + len * sin(angles)
  data.frame(xend = xend, yend = yend)
}
```

which returns a frame with the two desired columns. They can easily be added to existing data with `cbind(origdat, somefunc(...))`.